# pyvis network has double heading

Tags: python, graph, pyvis

I am using the following definition for the generation of a graph with pyvis:

> g = net.Network(notebook=True, width="100%", height="1500px", heading
> ="THIS APPEARS DOUBLE...", cdn_resources="in_line", select_menu=True)

However on the resulted graph I get the heading twice!

I am sure that I am creating only one graph though.

Any hint what happens there?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes seems issue induced in recent updates, issue created.
https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/issues/219

as a temporary solution, you may need to post process the generated html file to remove duplicate Header.

```py
html_str = nt.html.replace('</center>', 'xxxxxxx' + '</p>\n</center>')
# this actually edits heading, change code to remove second occurance
h = open(path,'w')
h.write(html_str)
h.close()
```

Comment: use this for removing 1 occurrence `re.sub(r'<center>.+?<\/h1>\s+<\/center>', '', nt.html, 1, re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to install the package from local and modify its source code (since this project is not under active maintainence).

1. `git clone https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis.git`
2. find the `template.html` file in the pyviz directory and remove these lines around line 34:

```html
<center>
  <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
</center>
```

3. `pip install -U .` This replaces your current installation by the local one.